# Excel Formula, 2 text cells each with 2 variables with technically 4 outcomes

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm sure this is very simple but i can't articulate well enough to find solution online. I have put image below of what i'm trying to do.
I have two columns one with states if 'completed' or 'incomplete' and a second that states 'in-date' or 'out of date'. I need the third column to display 3 possible outcomes.

- If complete AND in-date then display 'COMPLETE'
- If complete AND out of date then display "OUT OF DATE"
- If incomplete, irrespective of 2nd output need to display "INCOMPLETE"

I have tried various IF/AND/OR formulas etc all to no avail.

[image: Excel sheet I am working with]

Lots of formulas, but none that would satisfy all rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=IF(A2="Incomplete","Incomplete",IF(B2="In Date","COMPLETE","OUT OF DATE"))
```

should be sufficient.

Comment: Amazing, thank you - the things I tried were far more convoluted and over complicated. Thank you.